# What are your recommendations on a jQuery custom select element plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select, jquery-plugins

I've seen quite a few online and I thought I'd consult the Stack Overflow community for which they may have experience with and can make recommendations.

I basically am looking for a plugin that can replace a select element with

- custom dropdown that uses CSS (not tables)
- fair bit of flexibility with styles
- lightweight

Answer (score 3):

Personally I like **[jQuery Image ComboBox plugin](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)**

- it is easy to skin (provided `.css` file and no tables :) )
- lightweight, easy to inject images
- uses classic `<select />` and `<option />` elements

Comment: Don't really like using the title attribute for an image path. Would prefer defining that in an object literal when triggering the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

try [jQtransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) and [jQuery nice forms](http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jNice/). both are pretty good, easy to style and light weight