# How to get the selected ID of a UL / LI Box by Clicking on a Button - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox

I'm trying to get the Value of a Listbox made of li via button Click. I searched the web but the most solutions are with the onClick button on the listbox itself. 
I tried something like this.

Listbox:

```
echo("</head><body><ul id='selectable'>");

while($satz != null)
{
  echo "<li class='ui-widget-content' id='userid' value='$satz[ID]'>$satz[username]</li>";
  $satz=mysql_fetch_assoc($cursor);
}
echo("</ul></body></html>");
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#del").click(function()
{
var id = document.getElementById('selectable li').value;
alert(id);
```

But ID is undefined, what to do? Thanks.

Comment: `ul` element doesn't have `value` property. Also note that IDs must be  _unique_.

Comment: instead od value use data-value

Comment: The IDs are unique because I got them from the database. The Listbox is filled with users, ID and username included. How to get the selected ID of li?

Comment: _"The IDs are unique because I got them from the database."_ I meant ID attributes, not value of the `value` attributes, where is the `#del` element?

Comment: Oh, ok. The #del Button is on the same page like the JQuery Function and the Listbox. But the function of the listbox is on another page, I included the page with included_once. Did you meant the Id of the li tags? Is it wrong that they have the same ID called 'userid'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` element doesn't work like the `select` element, ie it doesn't have a selected option(value). That's why other solutions suggest listening to the click event of the `li` elements. You should either use a `select` element instead of the `ul` element:

```
$("#del").click(function() {
   var id = $('#selectable').val();
});
```

Or add an identifier like a specific className to the target `li` element:

```
$("#del").click(function() {
   var id = $('#selectable li.selected').attr('value');
});
```

That being said please note that your markup is invalid because:

1. You are using the same ID for several elements, IDs are supposed to be unique. Here classes should be used instead.
2. `value` is not a valid attribute for the `li` element, you should use `data-*` attributes instead. Then you can read the values using jQuery `.data()` method. Supposing you have a `data-value` attribute for reading the value, you can code:  `$('#selectable li.selected').data('value')`.
3. You are generating `body` element with it's contents and also including another page.

Comment: @Preprocezzor You are welcome. There are many plugins the let you customize the look of the selected elements like [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and [dropkick](https://github.com/Robdel12/DropKick)., just google `custom select`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually had already a version with select and option elements. I tried it with ul and li to design it easier. Do you have any suggestion to make it work with li elements? I added my css class into the option value but it doenst look like fancy like my li elements with the same css class. Do you have any suggestions to design a select listbox with optiion elements?

Comment: @Preprocezzor My first comment suggests some options. Also there are several related questions on SO like [What are your recommendations on a jQuery custom select element plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225833/what-are-your-recommendations-on-a-jquery-custom-select-element-plugin).